# Setting application-specific properties on deploy by maven

Tags: maven, tomcat8, webdeploy

I would like to deploy java app twice to one tomcat server, each time with different environment properties.

I would like to find a way like

```
mvn tomcat7:deploy -Denvironment=local
```

I don't mind using other maven plugin.

With no need to change files after deploy.
Is it somehow possible?
Thank you for you answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used little workaround. 
I created different profiles which I use to update application property.

example:
In my POM I have:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <properties>
            <environment>local</environment>
            ....
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

and in application.property file I have

```
environment=@environment@
```

(That @ are correct! )

This way I can deploy my app with defined environment by using command

```
mvn -P local tomcat7:deploy
```

and use environment variable anywhere else as ${environment}

Answer (score 0):

You can have a configuration file (something like e.g. `application.properties`) that you enable [resource filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) for. You could then parameterize the values in that configuration file, and pass in different parameter values for each of the deployments (`-Dkey1=value1 -Dkey2=value2`).

You could pass the different parameter values on the command-line, or you could cement them in [different profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), and just activate the appropriate profile from the command-line (`-Psecond-deployment`).

What seems a little unfortunate from the suggested approach in your question is: in its most basic sense Maven is a build tool, meant to produce a consistent artifact from a build. This is no longer the case with the suggested approach in your question. If this is a web application that is never used as a dependency of other module, this may be fine. But just highlighting that different deployment configurations is a deployment concern, not a *build* concern.